# matching 1 column from 2 different tables together in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 MySQL Databases,

one with a `customer` table and the other with a `client` table.

in the customer table there is a column called `customerid` and in the client table in the other database, a column called `parent_client_id`

i want to be able to select all data from the client table and make sure there is a row to match in the customer table.

i want to be able to show data from each row that from the client table that is not in the customer table

how can i do this using PHP?

i have tried this:

```
$sql="SELECT * from client ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from customer where customerid NOT IN( SELECT * from customer where customerid = '".$result["parent_client_id"]."' ) ";
    echo $sql2;
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    echo $result2["company"].'<br>';
}
```

but its not displaying the rows not matched

Answer (score 1):

You need `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM client LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.parent_client_id = client.id;
```

You provided not so much info so I may be wrong about query I gave, but you really need to use some `JOIN`, so I'll give you some stuff to read.

1. [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)
2. [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)
3. [`RIGHT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)
4. [`FULL JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)

---

After OP edit.

You are using `mysql_fetch_array` in wrong way, you should:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) 
{
    echo $row['company'] . '<br>';
}
```

As here probably are more results, however you probably want to have one single query, which is:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
FULL JOIN client 
ON client.parent_client_id = customer.customerid
WHERE customer.customerid 
NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT FROM customer
        INNER JOIN client
        ON client.parent_client_id = customer.customerid
        WHERE 1
    )
```

Comment: there are 2 different mysql_connect strings as they are 2 different databases

Comment: how do i connect the one query to 2 different databases? do i need a while loop for the latest query?

Comment: Do you have two different physical databases or you have one table in one db, another table in another db, but both are in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cl.* 
from client cl
inner join customer cu on cl.parent_client_id = cu.customerid
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: how do i display the results of what it not matched?

Comment: An inner join results only the matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM customer cu RIGHT JOIN client cl ON cu.parent_client_id = cl.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two different databases you need to prefix the table name with the database name in the SQL query. So:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from database1.customer where customerid NOT IN( SELECT parent_client_id from database2.customer) ";
```

(Where `database1` and `database2` are your database names.)

You'll also need to make sure the user that you use in your PHP connection has permission to acccess both databases of course.